# I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" for no reason (I think)

Tags: python, python-2.7

this is the code
`print(f"{DataBase.Count()} Users\n")`
and this is the error

```
    print(f"{DataBase.Count()} Users\n")
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and i dont know how to fix it please help me

Comment: f-strings were not available until Python 3.6.

Comment: You tagged the question `python-2.7`. In python2 `print` is a statement, not a function.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg, in fact `print()` was also available as a function in Python 2.7, but your response does make it clear why there's little point to ask about Python 2 these days, unless OP absolutely must use it - and in that case, they probably wouldn't be struggling with the problem they describe.

Comment: If you *must* use Python 2 (which is very rare, and a bad idea in general), you probably wanted `print('{} Users\n'.format(DataBase.Count()))`

Comment: `from __future__ import python3.6+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use fstring in python 2.7, you could use this lib: https://github.com/asottile-archive/future-fstrings

fstring is added after python 3.6.